# Azure release pipeline - If, Stage A fails Stage B should run all the jobs but it's skipping

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, azure-devops

[image]

We have an issue with Azure release pipeline, Once Stage A fails it should run Stage B, but all the tasks and jobs are skipping. Please find the below details. My condition is not correct I believe, could you please provide the valid condition expression.

[image]

Result needs: Once Stage A fails, Dependency Stage B should successfully run all the jobs and tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force the 2nd stage to run always by overriding its `condition:`, the default condition is `succeeded()`, but you can make it `succeededOrFailed()` or even `always()` (which will run even if cancelled):

```
stages:
- stage: A

# stage B runs if A fails
- stage: B
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

This requires the workflow to be built in YAML though, it's not possible in the "old" UI based releases.